# How to convert MySQL CONVERT_TZ() to Postgresql

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, greenplum

I got the below column in MySQL , I am trying to convert it into PostgreSQL but not able to do:

```
-- Mysql--
CONVERT_TZ(ORDER_CLOSE_DATE, 'PST8PDT', ifnull(CREATION_TIME_ZONE,'PST8PDT'))
as order_closed_date_TZ
```

Note : In the above I have two fields `ORDER_CLOSE_DATE` and `CREATION_TIME_ZONE`
I tried with below , but where/how I will set `CREATION_TIME_ZONE`?

```
-- Postgresql-->
to_char(timezone('America/Los_Angeles',o.ORDER_CLOSE_DATE::timestamp),
'yyyy-mm-dd hh:00:00') as order_closed_date_TZ
```

Comment: Have you checked `with time zone` and `at time zone` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used below only then got to know I was using correct syntax:

```
to_char(timezone('America/Los_Angeles',ORDER_CLOSE_DATE::timestamp),'yyyy-mm-dd hh:00:00') as order_closed_date_TZ
```